# Trouble importing photos from camera

Tags: windows-7, camera, import

I have a SONY DSC-W50 camera and Windows 7. I am having trouble importing from the camera to my Systemax computer. Do you have any suggestions to help me?

Comment: What error messages (if any) are you getting? Can you be more specific about the "trouble". There's not a lot go on here.

Comment: Like @ChrisF said, you need to supply way more information than that and [edit] your question -- What are you trying to do? What specifically fails? You could maybe add some screenshots, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to remove the memory card from the camera and insert it into the card reader on the PC if it has one, if it does not have one, USB card readers are inexpensive.